# In IE9 highlighting text in a disabled textbox won't release the mouse button; workaround?

Tags: textbox, internet-explorer-9, mouse, drag

I've found some odd behavior in IE9 that involves highlighting text inside a disabled textbox, dragging the cursor outside the textbox, releasing the mouse button, then attempting to click anything else inside the browser.  If the mouse is released outside the textbox, the browser acts as if the user didn't release the mouse button and doesn't allow the user to click on any other element on the page or even in the browser chrome itself.  To regain control of the mouse button, the user must either click inside the textbox again or double-click outside the textbox.

Is there a workaround in CSS or JS to keep this behavior from happening?

Here is a jsFiddle link where you can see the behavior for yourself.

http://jsfiddle.net/FQpRh/embedded/result/

And here is the HTML document that exhibits the behavior:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drag test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="Highlight me" />
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('hi');">Now try to click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: Have you tried just swallowing up the click events?  Add a handler to pick up the click events, call `preventDefault();`, and return.

Comment: I've tried to log all the events that occur on the input element on the console, but, when the element is disabled, there are no events fired. Sample code (see IE9 console within Developer tools F12) : http://jsfiddle.net/qKtsz/

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a working solution for this issue:

Catching the event on the parent element in which the input type="text" element finds itself and preventing its default functionality will do the trick

```
           elparent[0].addEventListener("selectstart", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
           });
```

Sample code :

http://jsfiddle.net/qKtsz/2/